# reusing a inner query in mysql select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> select a.catname as parent , b.catname as child from cmscat a , cmscat b where  
a.catrefid = (select ccmcatrefid1 as parentId from cmsccm where ccmrefid = 141) and 
b.catrefid= (select ccmcatrefid2 as childId from cmsccm where ccmrefid = 141);

+--------------+-----------------+
| parent       | child           |
+--------------+-----------------+
| Ceiling Fans | Decorative fans |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

It may be very basic question, I am getting what I want from my query, 
I just wanted to find out is there any way to shorten this query

I am looking a way in which I can use following query

```
select ccmcatrefid1 as parentId ,ccmcatrefid2 as childId from cmsccm 
where ccmrefid = 141;
```

instead of quering childId and parentId separately.

**--------------------------------------------------**
table structure

```
1 cmscat (category table)
it have (catrefid , catname)

2 cmsccm (category mapping table, it maps category as parent and child)
if have (ccmrefid ,ccmcatrefid1, ccmcatrefid2)
where ccmcatrefid1 and ccmcatrefid2 are id of cmscat table(catrefid)
```

Comment: You need to show the structure of your tables. Along with some sample data and desired output

Comment: SQL Fiddle would be perfect for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 3-way JOIN:

```
SELECT a.catname AS parent, b.catname AS child
FROM cmsccm AS c
JOIN cmscat AS a ON a.catrefid = c.ccmcatrefid1
JOIN cmscat AS b ON b.catrefid = c.ccmcatrefid2
WHERE c.ccmrefid = 141
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to access each table just once? Then join both, so as to get the two records in question. Then use a case construct to get the one or the other name and then aggregate to get one line showing both names.

```
select 
  max(case when cmscat.catrefid = cmsccm.ccmcatrefid1 then cmscat.catname end) as parentname,
  max(case when cmscat.catrefid = cmsccm.ccmcatrefid2 then cmscat.catname end) as childname
from cmscat
join cmsccm on cmscat.catrefid in (cmsccm.ccmcatrefid1, cmsccm.ccmcatrefid2)
where cmsccm.ccmrefid = 141;
```